# Kind-polymorphism in classes

Tags: haskell, ghc, higher-kinded-types

I [recently ran into a problem](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13365) using kind polymorphism with GADTs. The answer there was to give a "complete user-specified kind" (CUSK) for my data type. I've read the [relevant documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#complete-user-supplied-kind-signatures-and-polymorphic-recursion), but I'm still getting essentially the same error when I try to apply that to a class.

Concretely, once I give a CUSK, the following *does* compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, GADTs #-}

data Foo (x :: k) where
  C :: Foo x -> Foo '(x,x)
```

but when I move that definition to a class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}

class Foo (f :: k -> *) where
  foo :: (f :: k1 -> *) (x :: k1) -> (f :: (k1,k1) -> *) ('(x,x) :: (k1,k1))
```

I get the error:

```
• Expected kind ‘(k1, k1) -> *’, but ‘f’ has kind ‘k -> *’
• In the type signature:
    foo :: (f :: k1 -> *) (x :: k1) -> (f :: (k1, k1) -> *) ('(x, x) :: (k1, k1))
  In the class declaration for ‘Foo’
```

I expect there's something small I need to do to convince GHC that `f` is kind-polymorphic in the second example.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. As far as I know, kind polymorphism is prenex, and you want higher-rank kind polymorphism.

Comment: For what it's worth, the error you're getting is analogous to the type error in `foo :: Num a => (a -> a) -> (Int, Double) ; foo f = (f 0, f 0)`. Sure `a` can have any type, but it must be a monotype.

Comment: @Carl See the first link. I got higher-rank kind polymorphism with the GADT by adding a CUSK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for GHC 8 and `TypeInType`, which allows much more amusing forms of dependency. The following minor edit of your code typechecks.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, RankNTypes, KindSignatures,
    DataKinds, TypeInType  #-}

module KP where

import Data.Kind

class Foo (f :: forall k. k -> *) where
  foo :: (f :: k1 -> *) (x :: k1) -> (f :: (k1,k1) -> *) ('(x,x) :: (k1,k1))
```

Crucially, it is no longer a syntax error to use `forall` in the (ha ha!) *type* of a type class parameter.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different than the GADT example? Why do I need `TypeInType` here, but not there?

Comment: Well, before `TypeInType`, the correct kind annotation on `f` was a syntax error. And there's a genuine question of where `k` should be quantified: is it local to `f` or to `Foo`? Your GADT example, where you say "GADTs require kind signatures where they should be inferred...it's clear from the GADT constructors that `a :: *`" makes unwarranted assumptions about what is inferrable. For interesting patterns of abstraction, "guess the pattern" inference is now hopeless; "instantiate the pattern" inference is still pretty good, though.

Comment: In my GADT example, I managed to apply the first type parameter of `Foo` to two types of different kinds (namely `Nat` and `*`), without needing `TypeInType`. I think that's exactly what I'm trying to do in my example, so I'm not sure why the extension is required.

Comment: Write down the types (that we used to call "kinds") of the GADT constructor and the type class, with all `forall`s explicit. Your GADT has iiuc rank-1 polymorphism, but your typeclass has rank-2. Before `TypeInType` that (like a bunch of other stuff, e.g. GADT promotion) was beyond what was obviously manageable in GHC core. The `TypeInType` generalisation makes the treatment of polymorphism and equality constraints more uniform: equations between polymorphic types now work sensibly (i.e., heterogeneously), allowing higher-rank types in more places.

Comment: I edited the question to include a concrete GADT example. My understanding is that the constructor `C` requires rank-2 polymorphism, because we can never unify the kinds of `x` and `'(x,x)`. This is accomplished without `TypeInType`.

Comment: You are incorrect, as you can easily find out for yourself by asking `ghci`. Neither your GADT type constructor `Foo`, nor its value constructor `C` has a rank-2 polymorphic type: they do not need to abstract over polymorphic things. Your class `Foo` is not a translation to classes of your GADT, so you are making an apples-oranges comparison. The type of the class `Foo` is `(forall k. k -> *) -> Constraint` which really is rank-2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137392/discussion-between-crockeea-and-pigworker).

Comment: I gotta go to bed, but I'll look in in the morning. It's certainly possible that some things were disabled before `TypeInType` that might have been just about achievable, but once `TypeInType` became clearly the direction of travel, it wasn't worth thinking about how to squeeze them out of the old rules.

Comment: Ah. I thought `TypeInType` might have made this work, since it means kinds are no longer treated differently from types. I have no experience with it, though, obviously.

Comment: @Carl One way in which kinds are no longer treated differently from types is that you can have equational constraints on them (without needing a new level of constraint, as constraints on types will do). That's what allows GADT promotion, indexing by polymorphic things, etc.